# AppSync mutation that triggers more mutations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I have two tables: Posts and Users

In the `createPost` mutation resolver, I set some default values do certain properties (think userId, createdAt timestamp, isDeleted flag etc). In addition, I would like to increment the User's `numPosts` counter.

Is this possible via the standard resolvers?

If not, what's the better alternative and why?

**Alternative 1)** Use DynamoDB Stream and trigger lambda function when new Post record is added that increments User's `numPosts` counter.

**Alternative 2)** Use a lambda resolver and move all logic there instead of the standard resolver.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a BatchPut Operation to update multiple tables at the same time. Refer to [Amazon DynamoDB Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html) guide for more information.

You need to have a resolver like

```
{
  "version" : "2018-05-29",
  "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
  "tables" : {
    "Posts": {
        ...data
    },
    "NumPosts":{
        ...data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there is a risk that one of the operations completes without the rest.

Comment: That is correct. You should then look at the response and handle it accordingly. `BatchPut` operation in AppSync gives you a flexibility to perform partial updates when writing to multiple tables. However note that, each update to an item is an atomic operation.

I would suggest you use Alternative 1 - Use DynamoDB Stream and trigger lambda function when new Post record is added that increments User's numPosts counter. This way your state is eventually consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I went the route of "Use a lambda resolver and move all logic there instead of the standard resolver." for my app.

You have a lot of control this way, solid logging, metric, and can pretty much do whatever you want, but you have to then pay for lambda.

Your option of watching a stream might make more sense if the other changes could happen after the fact, and having the data in an in-between state didn't matter.

Hard to assess what the best option is without total context.

Answer (score -1):

There are [Update Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement) that can be used for DynamoDB; and it is apparently among the AppSync's [Resolver Mapping Template Reference for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-updateitem). Going through the sample code given in the code, it should be useful for you to operate through some `UpdateItem` code as follows:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "UpdateItem",
    "key": {
        "id" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.id}" }
    },
    "update" : {
        "expression" :  "ADD numPosts :incrCount",
        "expressionValues" : {
           ":incrCount" : { "N" : 1 }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This post assumes that your `numPosts` counter is kept as a field in your `Users` table.

Comment: Yes but in the same mutation I also want to update a property on User as well as on Post.